# How to escape special character Restful API query string in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, elk

I try to modify existing query string to filter specified condition:
now query string is below:

```
String bodycontent="{"
                +"  \"_source\": [\"@timestamp\",\"eqpid\",\"lotid\",\"stageid\",\"srvmethod\",\"parm_1\",\"apcack\",\"description\",\"host\",\"path\",\"action\"],"
                +"  \"query\": {"
                +"    \"query_string\" : {"
                +"        \"query\":\" lotid:"+q_lotid+" AND "+host_type+"\"}"
                +"  },"
                +"  \"sort\" : [{\"@timestamp\" : { \"order\" : \"desc\" }}]"
                +"}";
```

I want to change the query condition below:

```
query :
type:ams_log AND (alm_source:K*) AND (alm_id:TCS00004 OR alm_id:TCS00005 OR alm_id:TCS00007 OR alm_id:TCS00008 OR alm_id:TCS00009 OR alm_id:TCS00010 OR alm_id:TCS00011 OR alm_id:TCS00012 OR alm_id:TCS00013 OR alm_id:TCS00020 OR alm_id:TCS00024 OR alm_id:TCS00032)
```

but I am confused how to modify the query string with slash `\` and  Double quotes `"`.
I can't find the rule, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***Slash***     -   **`\\`**
- ***Quote*** - **`\"`**

---

```
System.out.println("\\ \"hello\"");
```

*Output:*

**`\ "hello"`**

---

*Regarding your query, seems like both key and value must be in between quotes* `"key":"value"`

```
String lotId="2020_A_88";
String type="apples";
String queryPart = "\"lotId\":\""+lotId+"\" AND \"type\":\""+type+"\"";
System.out.println(queryPart);
```

**`"lotId":"2020_A_88" AND "type":"apples"`**

---

```
String example = String.format("Slash-> %s , Quotes-> %s", "\\" ,"\"name\""); 
System.out.println(example);
```

**`Slash-> \ , Quotes-> "name"`**

---

```
String s = "\\";
String q = "\"name\"";
System.out.println("Slash-> "+s+" , Quotes-> "+q);
```

**`Slash-> \ , Quotes-> "name"`**

Comment: +"        \"query\":\" lotid:"+q_lotid+" AND "+host_type+"\"}"  could you explain this line? thanks!

Comment: It is incorrect, as includes a last quote in the host_type but not at the start. so the output would be something like:  `"query":" lotid:12 AND name"}`

Comment: `+  "\"query\":\" lotid:"+q_lotid+" AND \""+host_type+"\" \"}"` --> output --> `"query":" lotid:12 AND "name" "}`

Comment: note that you may need the last quote after "name"

Comment: it seems not correct, I try to change this line as you provide to JAVA file, and that's wrong.

Comment: I forgot to include the first \" from query, updated the comment. Try `+ "\"query\":\" lotid:"+q_lotid+" AND \""+host_type+"\" \"}"`  -- anyway, why is the last } needed?

Comment: Also, does the query need to be in between quotes? I don't get what's your desired output, could you tell?

Comment: I need to use restful api to query a remote database(in JAVA), so I need to process the query string with \ and "

Comment: it need } because it mapping the previous {

Comment: Could you modify my query string which I inquire >< I am very appreciated thanks. Because I have no idea how to modify.

Comment: updated the answer, but note that some databases may require single quotes when working with string literals, so I'll add that as well

Comment: I mean this query string-> 
query: type:ams_log AND (alm_source:K*) AND (alm_id:TCS00004 OR alm_id:TCS00005 OR alm_id:TCS00007 OR alm_id:TCS00008 OR alm_id:TCS00009 OR alm_id:TCS00010 OR alm_id:TCS00011 OR alm_id:TCS00012 OR alm_id:TCS00013 OR alm_id:TCS00020 OR alm_id:TCS00024 OR alm_id:TCS00032)

Comment: yes, but I want to change the original query string to the upper query string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226514/discussion-between-aran-and-howard).